# How to create email template in autosys

Tags: autosys

Lets say i have a job that runs for 10mins(lets say the time as 10.00). i set max_run_alarm as 3. i should get an email at 10.03 where i can goahead and see why the job is running more than the max_run_alarm. if i use max_run_alarm i am able to see in the logs triggering that alarm, but I cannot spend all day monitoring the logs to see which job is taking long as i have many jobs. my question is am i using max_run_alarm in the correct way or is there something else i am missing or is there entirely different way for the emails to generate.

Answer (score 0):

There is an added functionality where you can configure the email id where all Autosys notification to be sent out.
Incase of any event such as Job Failure / Termination / Run Alarms etc are notified to that email address.

This is configured by the Autosys Admin or the Scheduling Team which i call them as.